# C++ use string literal length value determined at compile time

Tags: c++, performance, c++17

Is the following a reasonable approach? Is there even a simpler way to avoid strlen() calls at runtime while keeping global constants defined as const char* const? I'm on C++17.

```
constexpr auto PREFIX = "myprefix";

std::string addPrefix(const std::string& s)
{
    static constexpr std::string_view prefix(PREFIX);
    std::string buf;
    buf.reserve(s.size() + prefix.size());
    buf += prefix;
    buf += s;
    return buf;
}
```

Comment: Is there some reason why you couldn't just use something like`constexpr auto PREFIX_SZ = sizeof(PREFIX) - 1;`?

Comment: Changed it to "reasonable approach", as the actual performance is secondary.

Comment: @paxdiablo this would not eliminate a call to strlen on buf += prefix, would it?

Comment: Whether or not it is reasonable depends on what your goal is. Are we to deduce your goal from your code? (If so, we're likely to conclude that your code exactly accomplishes your goal.)

Comment: @VladG it would. Both `string` and `string_view` store the length

Comment: At a guess, you are looking for [`std::literals::string_view_literals::operator""sv`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string_view/operator%22%22sv), as in `constexpr auto PREFIX = "myprefix"sv;`.

Comment: @bolov I meant that if I keep size as constexpr auto PREFIX_SZ = sizeof(PREFIX) - 1; it doesn't avoid a strlen() call when adding the literal to a std::string, but adding a string_view does as it knows its length

Comment: @paxdiablo well, it's error-prone (brittle anyway: what if `PREFIX` was a `char*` not a `const char[]` after someone edits the file), makes you deal with the -1 for the terminator, and now you have separate `PREFIX` and `PREFIX_SZ` rather than encapsulating them, contrary to GSL array advise in general.

Comment: Ok, I see std::string has append(const char* s, size_t n) which is what I'd use with the paxdiablo's suggestion, but it does appear that using std::string_view is cleaner.

Comment: @JaMiT wouldn't it make PREFIX a string_view? I want to keep it as const char*.

Comment: @VladG Oh,right. Sorry, I sometimes forget to account for pointless artificial restrictions. Is there a reason you don't allow global constants that are `string_view` or `size_t` or anything else that is not `const char * const`? *(If such a reason were to appear in the question, I might revise my assessment of the restriction being pointless and artificial.)*

Comment: @JaMiT no good reason except I got some pushback from a peer when I suggested to use something like constexpr std::string_view PREFIX = "myprefix";

Answer (score 1):

Yes, your code is performant.  You can paste it into Compiler Explorer, with optimization flags, to see the result.  The `string_view` will be done at compile time, and the length will be known at compile time so it doesn't do the counting off of `strlen`.

Is there a simpler way?  Yes, but essentially the same thing just packaged to be reusable.  I have (as do big libraries such as absil) an `append` function that takes any number of arguments, and does just that:  adds up the lengths first, reserves, then copies.

A `constexpr string_view` is a very understandable way to get the length at compile-time, and it is generally good at replacing raw character literals because you get all the `string` class members on it etc, and you don't get distracted by the allocation for the trailing `\0`.  A more "minimal" way won't be any faster (after all, it's being done at compile time) and you have a separation between the string pointer and the length rather than encapsulating them, and you use an odd rare technique instead of this general one.  So, just use this.  It's good.

## update

As Jarod42 points out, `PREFIX` as you defined it has type `const char*`.
To clarify, the [lexical string literal](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/string_literal) `"myprefix"` has type `const char[9]`.  But the way you used `auto` it decays to a pointer.  Even so, the `constexpr` [constructor for `string_view`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string_view/basic_string_view) takes a `const char*` and scans for the terminating `\0`, so having the length of the array does not help (you could have a nul in the middle of the array).

You should declare constant lexical string literals like this:

```
constexpr char s1[] = "the letters";
```

because it directly names the array of characters.  If you write:

```
constexpr const char* s2 = "more letters";
```

you end up with another chunk of memory to represent the pointer, which is what gets named `s2`, in addition to the actual array of characters.

Your use of `auto` is the same as `s2`.

Comment: `PREFIX` is a `const char*const` [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/hPzv5v11G), it would need `auto&` [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/YzKnvW1jn)

Comment: `"myprefix"` is a `const char[9]`, `PREFIX` is a `conct char* const`. decay already happened. See the demo links.